# How to convert this Swift syntax into Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm converting a swift project to objective c, but i get some trouble because i don't know how to convert follow code. Please help me. Thanks!

```
   public enum UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode {
    case fixed(spacing: CGFloat)
    case overlap(visibleOffset: CGFloat)
}
```

and

```
fileprivate var currentPage: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        let character = self.items[self.currentPage]
        self.infoLabel.text = character.name.uppercased()
        self.detailLabel.text = character.movie.uppercased()
    }
}
```

Comment: The first snippet cannot be converted to Objective-C because an enum with associated types is not available in ObjC. The second snippet can be converted by implementing the explicit setter of the property.

Comment: Converting Objective-C to Swift is a much easier task than trying to do a one-to-one conversion from Swift to Objective C. Swift's enums are unique and powerful, I doubt you'll find a simple way to convert it to Swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first (an `enum` with associated values) has no direct equivalent in Objective-C. For your particular example, you could use something like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode) {
    UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingModeFixed,
    UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingModeOverlap
};

typedef struct {
    UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode mode;
    CGFloat amount;
} UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing;
```

You would just pass around values of type `UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing`. You could create helper functions to make these easier to create, e.g.

```
UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMakeFixed(CGFloat spacing) {
    UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing value;
    value.mode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingModeFixed;
    value.amount = spacing;
    return value;
}

UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMakeOverlap(CGFloat visibleOffset) {
    UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacing value;
    value.mode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingModeOverlap;
    value.amount = visibleOffset;
    return value;
}
```

For the second, you can override the setter method of your Objective-C class's `currentPage` property:

```
- (void)setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page {
    _page = page;

    MovieCharacter *character = self.items[page];
    self.infoLabel.text = character.name.localizedUppercaseString;
    self.detailLabel.text = character.movie.localizedUppercaseString;
}
```